# ArrayList<Bitmap> returns same bitmap

Tags: android, arraylist, timer, bitmap, screen-capture

I'm trying to capture multiple screenshots at regular interval using `Timer`.
But; the images added to the `ArrayList` are all last images. So I'm getting similar images throughout the list.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                System.out.println("executing timer "+index);

                View rootView = findViewById(R.id.relative_inside);
                rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                rootView.buildDrawingCache();

                Bitmap drawingCache = rootView.getDrawingCache();
                list.add(drawingCache);

                System.out.println("image added to list "+index);
                index++;
            }
        }); 
    }
};
```

I'm calling timer with the below code :-

```
timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 80);
```

but, while extracting the images from List, I'm getting similar images. Could anyone point out my mistake?

Comment: where is list object defined ?

Comment: ArrayList<Bitmap> list = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(); is defined in Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `getDrawingCache()` returns the same instance of `Bitmap`, just with updated pixel data. Therefore, all list items already added are getting updated whenever cache bitmap change.

You would have to create new instance of Bitmap every time you read cache and then add to the list.

For example:

```
Bitmap drawingCache = Bitmap.createBitmap(rootView.getDrawingCache());
list.add(drawingCache);
```

Please note that bitmaps consume a lot of memory and it's very easy to get `OutOfMemoryError`.

Additionally, you could move this part:

```
View rootView = findViewById(R.id.relative_inside);
rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
rootView.buildDrawingCache();
```

to TimerTask creation phase e.g. inside constructor. Then you can refer to your view by instance variable. Going through view hierarchy is time consuming.

Comment: That works if I store around 111-112 images, but as the count goes to 125 images as total, it throws OutOfMemoryError exception. What can I do for that?

Comment: You could set android:largeHeap in your manifest but it's not recommended most of the time. Unfortunately, apps have limited memory and bitmaps are those that consume it the most. If you really need all these bitmaps at once then you have to design your app different way. If not, consider storing those bitmaps in filesystem and whenever you need them for display use caching mechanism http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html or existing libraries like Picasso for efficient bitmap presentation.

Comment: I need all those bitmaps for later use. I'll be saving all these Bitmaps later after the execution of my whole animation. And in what different way are you asking me to modify my app. Please elaborate.

Comment: Sometime technical restrictions does not allow perform certain task which ends with design change. It depends on application but it seems to be not the case. If you need those bitmaps for later then store them immediately releasing bitmap after being stored. Then optimize the use of bitmaps in your animations, use as many as needed at a time. For that you have to get familiar with caching bitmaps, see link from previous comment. It's complex task and I can't give you out of the box solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bitmap return by `getDrawingCache()` is always the same as long as you don't recycle the Bitmap or don't call `setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);` or `destroyDrawingCache()`.